# Pandas Dataframe Plotting fails due to date "ValueError: view limit minimum 0.0 is less than 1 and is an invalid Matplotlib date value."

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plot

I have a pandas data frame with few columns, I am trying to plot two of these columns using matplotlib, but the below code keeps failing every alternate try on Zeppelin. Not sure, what I am missing here.

```
type(df3pd)
```

class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'

```
df3pd.dtypes

grouping_column                int64
day                            object
metric_ratio                   float64
metric_ratio2             float64
dtype: object
```

Here is my current plotting code. This keeps failing the first time I run it in my Zeppelin notebook, but executes successfully if I run it the second time.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

dfnew3pd = df3pd[df3pd['grouping_column'] == 450123][['day','metric_ratio2']]

x = pd.to_datetime(dfnew3pd.day)
y = dfnew3pd.metric_ratio2

plt.style.use('ggplot')
plt.clf()
plt.plot(x,y)
plt.show()
```

Here is the error that keeps coming every first time I run this plot code, but disappears the second time and plot comes up correctly.

```
File "/usr/local/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/dates.py", line 1269, in refresh
    dmin, dmax = self.viewlim_to_dt()
  File "/usr/local/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/dates.py", line 1026, in viewlim_to_dt
    .format(vmin))
ValueError: view limit minimum 0.0 is less than 1 and is an invalid Matplotlib date value. This often happens if you pass a non-datetime value to an axis that has datetime units
```

Comment: You would want to make your case reproducible for others, see [mcve]. Else one cannot find out about the problem.

Answer (score 1):

What if you try sticking to `Series.plot`?

```
v = df3pd[df3pd['grouping_column'] == 450123]
v.set_index('day').metric_ratio2.plot()
plt.show()
```

Comment: Thanks for quick reply! It also fails the first time I run it, and succeeds the second time. Repeats this pattern. I am guessing I am missing something very simple here. I use Zeppelin and Spark on AWS EMR. ---- same error -  File "/usr/local/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/dates.py", line 1026, in viewlim_to_dt
    .format(vmin))
ValueError: view limit minimum 0.0 is less than 1 and is an invalid Matplotlib date value. This often happens if you pass a non-datetime value to an axis that has datetime units